# bash script to access multiple mysql databases

Tags: mysql, bash, sh

I all,

I have a series of MYSQL databases with different users and passwords, nevertheless the DB structure is the same for all databases.
I can't create a user with the same username and password to all of them and I need to quickly perform operations on all of them.

I was thinking about a bash script to run via cron.

Any suggestion? I was thinking to something like this but it is not working :(

```
#!/bin/bash
uconn=(
            'mysql -u user_db1         --password=pass_db1      db1      '
            'mysql -u user_db2         --password=pass_db2      db2      ' 

             )

for f in "${uconn[@]}"
do
    exec ${f}
    echo `mysql show tables`
    echo `mysql exit`
done
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) way?

```
do
  ${f} <<EOF
show tables
\\q
EOF
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pasting the full code taking into consideration @Ansgar Wiechers:

```
#!/bin/bash
uconn=(
            'mysql -u user_db1 --password=pass_db1  db1'
            'mysql -u user_db2 --password=pass_db2  db2' 

             )

for f in "${uconn[@]}"
    do
      ${f} <<EOF
    show tables
    \\q
    EOF
    done
exit
```

To execute the code from the local machine to the remote one this works for me:

```
ssh ssh_user@mydomain.com 'bash -s' < /local/path/to/multiple_db_connections.sh
```

where the content of **multiple_db_connections.sh** is the code above